# Three-log problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, equilibrium

[image: problem sketch]

Three uniform round rigid cylindrical logs of the same size and weight are placed on a horizontal plane. The two at the bottom are touching each other, the third one is placed on the top as shown in the picture. The coefficient of friction between any two logs is $\mu_1$, the coefficient of friction between any log and the floor is $\mu_2$. For some asymptotic values of $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ one can immediately conclude about existence or non-existence of equilibrium. For example if both $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ are zero then obviously there is no equilibrium. Further, one can argue that if either $\mu_1$ or $\mu_2$ is zero than there is no equilibrium no matter what the other coefficient is. In general, for what values of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ would this system be in equilibrium?

P.S. The problem is currently closed for some obscure reasons; but if you like it please vote to reopen it (the link is below), and then perhaps we can discuss the solution.

Comment: @Danu: After I invented this problem recently of course I solved it myself first :). Then, since I thought this is such a nice little physics problem I decided to post it here for entertainment of the community. Is there anything wrong with that? Isn't the purpose of this website to provide entertaining physics problems and discussions? Somehow it ended up being put on hold by some moderators of this group, not sure what their issue was, this is just a little elegant physics brainteaser.

Comment: These were not moderators, but regular users who reached some reputation level. The question such as this are indeed off topic: homework-and-exercises questions are supposed to show some research effort and in general to ask conceptual questions, not just pose some fun problems to solve. Anyway, the put-on-hold message already says this.

Comment: @Ruslan All right, I've done the "research effort", I would be happy just to post the solution if anyone would care to look at it.

Comment: @MaximUmansky (3 comments up) Well... yes, there is something (slightly) wrong with that. This is not a site for brainteasers, it's a site for people with real, practical questions that they have tried to solve and are unable to on their own.

Comment: @DavidZ This toy problem is a way to approach the real problem that I am interested in which is [stability of a conical heap of pebbles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241380/heap-of-pebbles).